# How can I debug VGA Out on an iPad?

Tags: iphone, debugging, ipad

The Dock Connector to VGA Adapter (required for VGA out on the iPad) uses the Dock Connector, so I can't have my laptop connected at the same time.

I remember reading something about a Remote debugger, but despite lots of searching, I'm unable to find it.

How can I run the debugger to test VGA output of my iPad app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator now supports simulating TV Out in iOS 3.2 and 4.0.

Comment: To do this in the iPhone Simulator: Hardware -> TV Out -> (Then select desired screen res to simulate)

Answer (score 2):

iPhoneOS 3.1 only allows [instrumentation over Wi-Fi](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008407-CH1-SW17), not debugging. I would have suggested buying an adapter with two female connectors, but a google search unfortunately found no such piece of hardware :-(

Comment: I think the iPad only supports iPhoneOS 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

the apple composite out cable (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB129LL/B) and it looks like the component out as well (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB128LL/B) uses the same API as VGA out when connected (though only at 480i) yet has a connector that plugs into the ipad and the computer at the same time.  though it's not VGA res, it's very useful to test on hardware (there are lots of reasons why this is better than the simulator).